# Problems getting a vertical value from a 2d value turned into a 1d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, for-loop, math, multidimensional-array

I have a program that loads a 2d array in a 1d array. I can't use a 2d array for this example.

**2 Dimensional**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**1 Dimensional**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I have a nested `for loop` to access the horizontal values which works fine, but I don't know how I can do this for the vertical loop. The idea is that the program loads all possible numbers with at least two numbers so the first horizontal row would be:

```
12 123 23
```

I want to achieve the same for the vertical rows so:

```
14 147 47
```

**Code**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    word = array[i]

    for(int j = 1; j < 3-i%3; i++){
       word+= array[i+j]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the code does what you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    word = array[i]

    for(int j = 1; j < 3-i/3; j++){
       word+= array[i+3*j]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that it could be that simple :D